Joint compond on top of primer is deteriorating the primer
In leveling the surface of a painted drywall I applied joint compound, sanded and then applied a water-based primer. After drying I could still see areas that need filling/leveling, but when I reapplied joint compound it immediately softened the primer and on a second pass of a trowel knife the whole surface started to pull off. How to get out of this mess? Is there a different primer I can use that won't deteriorate when I apply the joint compound on top? Thanks,

How long did you let the primer dry? My initial suspicion is that the primer wasn't fully cured when you put the mud on top of it.

Don't use primer. Compound does not need primer to stick.   If you do use a primer allow 24 hours to dry.

The primer coat was dried for a few days. When I applied the added joint compound to fill imperfections (those I couldn't see until the primer was on it) the wet compound softened the primer immediately, released it and pulled off with the first layer of compound underneath. So I have to clean it up and start over, but feel I need to find a different primer. Would an oil-based primer be the way to go on this interior wall? Any thoughts appreciated.

Why don't you get the smoothness you want from the wall before applying the primer?
